# Como realizar dos sentencias de MySql (Insert y Update) en una sola instruccion?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagrid

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa en C# el cual inserta datos a mi DB desde un datagridview de esta forma:

```
conexion.Close();

        string instruccion2 = "INSERT INTO pedidoproducto(codigo_Orden_Pedido, codigo_Producto, piezas_Solicitadas, precio, descripcion, costocimp, proveedor) VALUES (?codigo_Orden_Pedido, ?codigo_Producto, ?piezas_Solicitadas, ?precio, ?descripcion, ?costocimp, ?proveedor)";
        conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand agregar = new MySqlCommand(instruccion2, conexion);
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                agregar.Parameters.Clear();
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?codigo_Orden_Pedido", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = NumeroOrdenTxt.Text;
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?codigo_Producto", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["CODIGO"].Value);
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?piezas_Solicitadas", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["CANTIDAD"].Value);
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?precio", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["PRECIO"].Value);
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?descripcion", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["NOMBRE"].Value);
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?costocimp", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["COSTOCIMP"].Value);
                agregar.Parameters.Add("?proveedor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["PROVEEDOR"].Value);
                agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("PEDIDO GENERADO");
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

ahora tengo que realizar un update a otra tabla , utilizando el mismo Datagridview y lo que no quiero es que tenga que realizar las dos instrucciones por separado ( una para el insert y otra para el update), hay alguna forma de enviar dos comandos en el mismo `ExecuteNonQuery()` ?

Comment: Mejor usa un SP y realizas todo dentro el sp el modo de llamarlo es casi igual que como lo usas,. :D

Comment: y si mejor usas MysqlTransaction y dentro del bloque puedes ejecutar, Select, insert, delete y update es una solo transaccion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un ejemplo para realizar la transaccion como te puse en el comentario.

```
public void transaction()
    {
        MySqlConnection consem = new MySqlConnection("toconexion");
        MySqlCommand comsem = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter adpsem = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        consem.Open();
        MySqlTransaction transem = consem.BeginTransaction();
        comsem.Transaction = transem;
        try
        {

            //borramos
            query = "DELETE...";
            comsem.CommandText = query;
            comsem.Connection = consem;
            adpsem.DeleteCommand = comsem;
            comsem.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //actualizamos
            query = "Udate...";
            comsem.CommandText = query;
            comsem.Connection = consem;
            adpsem.UpdateCommand = comsem;
            comsem.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //insertamos
            query = "INSERT INTO ...)";
            comsem.CommandText = query;
            comsem.Connection = consem;
            adpsem.InsertCommand = comsem;
            comsem.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transem.Commit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transem.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            consem.Close();
        }
    }
```

Checa si te sirve y comentas como te va...

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo eso necesitaba, ya solo me falta buscar como mandar un mensaje cuando se realizo la transaccion con exito, por que solo lo hace pero no avisa ni nada